# Pass Method as parameter for another Method in Java

Tags: java, button, methods, parameters, listener

I am creating a generic method to create action listeners for buttons, and i would like to be able to pass in another method into it's actionPerformed, rather than creating a new method for each use case of a listener. something like this:

```
public static ActionListener makeListener(Method method) {
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            method();
        }
    };
    return listener;
}
```

Other similar posts have had recommended Lambda Expressions, but (maybe due to a lack of understanding), I don't think those are what i need. Are there other options?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a `Runnable` is exactly what you need.

Declaration:

```
public static ActionListener make_listener(JButton button, Runnable action) {
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            action.run();
        }
    };
    return listener;
}
```

Or using a lambda for the `ActionListener` (and skipping the local variable):

```
public static ActionListener make_listener(JButton button, Runnable action) {
    return e -> action.run();
}
```

You can now call it with any zero-argument method using a lambda or method reference:

```
ActionListener listener1 = make_listener(() -> callMethod());
ActionListener listener2 = make_listener(this::callMethod);
```

Comment: Or just `return action::run`. But if you use a lambda to create the `Runnable`, then `ActionListener listener1 = this::callMethod` would work as well.

Comment: `action::run` is not an `ActionListener` because of the `e` argument. Assigning `this::callMethod` to an `ActionListener` variable only works if `callMethod` has a single argument of type `ActionEvent`.

Comment: Right - but still, using `() ->` vs `e ->` makes the method still pointless.

Comment: It should be named `makeListener`, not `make_listener`.

Comment: I think that the question originally had `make_listener` and I copied it from there, because I wouldn't use snake case in Java code myself.